# Does java put objects local to a function on the stack?

Tags: java, function, heap-memory, stack-memory

Simply wondering, can't find an answer (in the way I'm formulating the question, a least):

if I have something like this:

```
double compute(double input)
{
   return new Computer(input).run();
}
```

and supposing that the `Computer` class methods don't interfere with any other classes, will the compiler/jvm allocate the class instance on the stack? (not talking about language specification here but  hidden optimization)

More generally, is there a way to have zero-overhead allocations for function-local objects by following specific constraints?

Comment: Objects are always stored in the heap. The reference to the object is in the stack.

Comment: "is there a way to have zero-overhead allocations" you leave it to the JVM. If it can determine (via escape analysis) that there is no need to allocate the object, it doesn't.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's not about not allocating at all, but if the JVM tries to determine that it can allocate on the stack. Or is that what you meant?

Comment: In general, the Computer constructor or its run method could pass on references to its object that outlive the execution of the run call.  If the object were on the stack, this would lead to disaster.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's why I said (poorly) "Computer class methods don't interfere with any other classes". No matter, the answer to my question is "sort of, but not really" apparently : https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/18-scalar-replacement/

Comment: @schmop no, I say again: objects are always stored on the heap. The JVM may be able to avoid creating the object if it can determine that it doesn't need to, by storing the members in the stack - but if those members are themselves references to objects, it's the reference that's on the stack, the objects are still in the heap.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok, I got it now. Thanks

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called _escape analysis_, and while there's been talk for a long time of implementing it in the JVM, I don't believe it is in real-world implementations, and even if it were it would be invisible to the JVM's formal machine model.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- There's plenty of escape analysis in the JVM (since version 6 I think). It's just not used for precisely the optimization I was thinking of.

Comment: There was some work on stack allocation earlier this year: https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk-proposals/blob/master/stack_allocation/Stack_Allocation_JEP.md Don't know if that's still going. One of the problems with stack allocation is that you can't e.g. displace thread stacks without doing a bunch of patching (if there are pointers to stack allocated objects). So, this wouldn't play well with Loom's virtual threads for instance. It was suggested to use a side-buffer to do watermark based allocations, which seemed like a good idea to me, but haven't heard anything else after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(taken from the comments under the OP)

The JVM may be able to avoid creating the object if it can determine that it doesn't need to, by storing the members in the stack - but if those members are themselves references to objects, it's the reference that's on the stack, the objects are still in the heap.
(part of scalar replacement optimization: https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/18-scalar-replacement/)

There was some work on stack allocation earlier this year: https://github.com/microsoft/openjdk-proposals/blob/master/stack_allocation/Stack_Allocation_JEP.md … Don't know if that's still going. One of the problems with stack allocation is that you can't e.g. displace thread stacks without doing a bunch of patching (if there are pointers to stack allocated objects).